# bash script read line by line

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting, awk

Hello I am trying to create a script that reads my file take all the variable it needs then use it for another command.
But it seems that the variables are not being memorized,  because I tried a printf instead of running my script and I got an empty output.

here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
numparams=$#
params=$*
cat tots.txt | while read;
do  awk '{
regid=$1;
uport=$2;
ongoingcalls=$3;
ingeg=$4;
maxcalls=$5;
if($3<$5) state=0
if($3==$5) state=1
if($3>$5) state=2
}'
/home/send_script.sh -o "$regid $uport $ongoingcalls $ingeg $maxcalls $state"
done
```

And here is the tots.txt content:

[image]

Comment: And by "the variables are not being memorized", you mean exactly what?

Comment: so for example if afte the awk command I type printf "$regid" it will give me nothing.

Comment: Well, `awk` variables are not `bash` variables. You would need to assign the result of `awk` to `bash` variables. But you don't need `awk` at all in this case. I'd just use `bash` features.

Comment: Play around with 1) `test` aka `[]` to set `state` and 2) the following snippet: `while read line; do set $line; echo $1 $2 $3 $4; done` and you'll get where you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your variables are being set in the subshell you open by saying `cat <file> | while ...`. So when this subshell is done, you cannot access to those variables any more.

Instead, say:

```
while read; do
    ...
done < tots.txt
```

Interesting reading: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Note also that you seem to have some confusion between `awk` and `shell` variables. Whatever you set in `awk` will remain there, so saying `awk '{$var=2}'` is two times incorrect: variables in awk are set without the `$` (`$var` will refer to the column number `var`) and then the var is just in the scope of `awk` and not available in your shell.

Maybe you want to do something like:

```
results=($(awk 'BEGIN {print 1,2,3,"a"}'))
```

So that you create an array `results[]` that you can later on access.